# Looking for Employee age using Sysdate in SQL

Tags: sql

I just started learning SQL and I have a question on the sysdate function.
We are given a table with the **emp_dob** (employee date of birth) and we are required to find their age.

The solution would be

```
SELECT emp_fname "First Name"
     , emp_lname "Last Name"
     , round ((sysdate-emp_dob)/365,2) "Employee Age"
  from emp
 order 
    by "Employee Age" desc;
```

My question is why does it have to be divided by 365 to find the age.

Why can't it just be sysdate - date of birth.

Thanks

Comment: Use DateDiff function if you are using SQL , Eg. SELECT DATEDIFF(year, '2017/08/25', '2011/08/25') AS DateDiff;  More info https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp

Comment: SYSDATE is an oracle function not available in mysql. Are you sure you are using mysql?

Comment: ...(and so, presumably, is `date_x-date_y`)

Comment: @RohitKumar the question was tagged as `mySQL`, `DATEDIFF` is available in `SQL-Server`, but not exists in `mySQL`.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan User has edited tag multiple times, at the point I suggested it was for SQL and currently also the tag is mentioned as SQL.

Comment: @RohitKumar Ok.

Comment: what dbms are you using(`mysql` or `oracle`) ?

Answer (score 0):

Dates are stored internally as a floating point number where the integer part reports the number of days and the fractional part the time within the day.
Substracting the date of birth from `NOW()` or `SYSDATE` (depends on the database you use), you therefore get the number of days the person in question has been living.
Dividing by 365 you get its age.

Of course, using the function `DATEDIFF` would be better since in that case you don't depend on internal implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I have another way, but not sure if it's good or not.

Extract only year and then minus like:

```
SELECT (YEAR(SYSDATE) - YEAR(emp_dob)) AS "Employee Age" FROM table_name
```

Comment: This wouldn't work example : Todays Date : 11-Oct-2018 and Dob : 10-Sep-2017 where the age comes as less than 1 year but as per suggested formula age would come out a 1 Year.

Comment: Thanks, I understand your point but from your example 
SYSDATE: 11-Oct-2018 and DOB: 10-Sep-2017 I have calculated and result is 396 days it is more that 1 year
May be you mean SYSDATE: 11-Oct-2018 and DOB: 15-Oct-2017 it's will be 361 days it is less than 1 year like what are you telling right?

Comment: Sorry I did mistakenly used the reverse date it was to be 11-Oct-2018 and 10-Nov-2017

Comment: It's okay, I understand you :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `timestampdiff` function with `year` argument and `truncate` function as :

```
select truncate(timestampdiff(year,emp_dob,current_date),2) as age 
  from tab;
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/HNSQX42758)